# Certain binaries run while others don't (despite ls visibility and +x) from mod_perl2 script

Tags: linux, perl, apache2.2, mod-perl2, qx

On Apache 2.2 on CentOS 6.4 with perl 5.10.1.

I'm trying to get a remote directory listing from within a mod_perl script, which apparently (if I `die qx(id)`) is running as `apache`.  But I'm not even getting as far as being able to run `ssh` without parameters, just to have it print its help info.  So that's what I'm asking how to do in this question--it's not about `ssh` not being able to connect.

```
die qx(which ssh);
```

dies with:

```
/usr/bin/ssh
```

and:

```
die qx(ls -al /usr/bin/ssh);
```

dies with:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 376920 Feb 21  2013 /usr/bin/ssh
```

Okay, so, it can find it, and see it, and has execute rights on it (which is true for /usr/bin and /usr as well.)  But then:

```
die qx(/usr/bin/ssh); # or just 'ssh'
```

dies with an empty array, so I tried:

```
system("ssh") == 0 or die "failed: $! (code $?)"; # or '/usr/bin/ssh'
```

...which dies with:

```
No such file or directory (code 65280)
```

Why is this?  How can I get `die qx(ssh)` or `die qx(/usr/bin/ssh)` to die with the expected value of:

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

Interestingly, from a bash prompt I get this:

```
$ sudo su apache ssh
This account is currently not available.
```

So...how can I run `ls` from an account that's not available, yet not `ssh`?  They're both programs, why do they behave differently here?

Update:  It's not just `ssh`, but I can't figure out the pattern: `gawk`, `tar`, and `ping` also don't work.  Yet `df`, `ls`, `dir`, and `pwd` all do.  But:

```
$ ls -al /bin/ls
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 109208 May 23 07:00 /bin/ls
$ ls -al /usr/bin/dir
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 109208 May 23 07:00 /usr/bin/dir
$ ls -al /bin/pwd
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 28008 May 23 07:00 /bin/pwd
$ ls -al /bin/df
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 73808 May 23 07:00 /bin/df

$ ls -al /bin/gawk
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 375360 Aug  7  2012 /bin/gawk
$ ls -al /bin/tar
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 390616 Feb 21  2013 /bin/tar
$ ls -al /usr/bin/ssh
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 376920 Feb 21  2013 /usr/bin/ssh
$ ls -al /bin/ping
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 40760 Jun  5 06:39 /bin/ping
```

So they all have all the 'x' bits set (except ping with its one 's', yet see below its error code), and for example, `ssh` and `dir` have identical ACLs.  So why should `ssh` and `gawk` fail to give any output but `dir` and `ls` succeed?  (Full paths or no.)

Update: even more perplexingly, `/bin/gawk` fails with the same message but code 256, and `/bin/tar` and `/bin/ping` similarly but code 512.

Update: OK, this part makes sense: If I run the failing binaries from the command line and then run `echo $?` immediately after, `ssh` gives 255, `ping` and `tar` give 2, and `gawk` gives 1.  Those are scaled-down versions of what I get in mod_perl2.  So, it seems to be that anything with a return code other than 0 doesn't work.  Possibly it's outputting to STDERR, and so STDOUT doesn't capture anything, hence the blank return.

Aha, that's the answer--will post.

Comment: Whoa Nelly. Please reconsider your application architecture. Launching SSH commands from a web script is questionable on several levels. Could you consider running the ssh commands from cron and writing the output to a file, for instance?

Comment: Maybe selinux prevents this?

Comment: @MikkoLipasti, it's an intranet script controlling a restore on a remote server.  I need to get a list of backups available to restore from.

Comment: @SlavenRezic, selinux is completely disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you redirect STDERR to also capture it in your qx, like so:

```
die qx(ssh 2>&1);
```

...you'll get the output you get on the command line.  So it's not that it's not running, it's just that it doesn't write anything to STDOUT.